# Magento 2.2, product image shows in grid and search templates, does not show on detail page

Tags: magento2, product-images

After Importing products using cart2cart, the product images will show everywhere **EXCEPT** on the product detail page

> Grid view on "new items template"
>
> Grid and List view on "product category page"
>
> Within the admin, during search
>
> during checkout in the mini cart and full cart

Where it **DOES NOT** show is on the product detail page.  Unless I add a second image.  Once a second image is added, it will display both in a gallery

The theme is a basic template based on "magento blank" with very few modifications (mainly css and a few xml settings to move or add blocks), there is no theme override on the product view page

I have tried

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Thubnail-for-product-page-not-showing-for-single-image/td-p/91916)

copy fotorama.js out of the default, into your theme

from

> lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js

into

> app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/web/fotorama/fotorama.js

find the following function `setOptions() {}` and set `if (size > 1)` to `if (size >= 1)`

```
if (size >= 1) { // change this line
    o_nav = opts.nav;
    o_navTop = opts.navposition === 'top';
    classes.remove.push(selectClass);

    $arrs.toggle(opts.arrows);
} else {
    o_nav = false;
    $arrs.hide();
}
```